# Why do clouds not fall?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science, buoyancy

The density difference between the clouds and the atmosphere favours the clouds to fall. Why don't they?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Density of Clouds](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9898/)